# Python script to give input to exe

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am able to open cmd.exe using script

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",shell=True)
```

But I am unable to send input command to cmd.exe open.
I want to achieve something like below mentioned using script

1) script give input command like `python` to cmd.exe open
[image]

2) After that script give input command like `print "hello"` to python prompt comes
[image]

Comment: open python from python?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Python to create a batch file that prints what you want, then execute that batch file? You could either return immediately or keep the command interpreter open: it depends on the command switches you use to run the batch file.

Comment: I know that can be done, but what I want to know is how to give input to any xyz.exe open through python script.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file hello.py containing `print "hello"`, and run it through cmd ?

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "hello.py"])
```

Comment: I know that can be done, but what I want to know is how to give input to any xyz.exe open.

Comment: Check this !http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771941/open-text-file-in-notepad-using-subprocess-popen  @user3767070

Comment: not useful, as I am able to open exe, but unable to give input to that exe